# PHPUnit code coverage breaks when defining variables for the same class ($this->example)

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit, code-coverage

As soon as I try to define a variable which will be accessible in the entire class ($this->variable, for example), this breaks PHPunit code coverage.

From that point on, PHPUnit claims the code isn't being executed (while it is in fact being executed, the test even passes).

[Screenshot of Code Coverage suddenly stopping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ioC7k.png)

```
........................                                          24 / 24 (100%)

Time: 01:07.127, Memory: 56.00 MB

OK (24 tests, 29 assertions)

Generating code coverage report in HTML format ... done [00:11.315]
```

Here's my phpunit config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="./vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit.xsd"
         bootstrap="vendor/autoload.php"
         beStrictAboutCoversAnnotation="false"
         colors="true"
>

    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="Unit">
            <directory suffix="Test.php">./tests/Unit</directory>
        </testsuite>
        <testsuite name="Feature">
            <directory suffix="Test.php">./tests/Feature</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>

    <coverage cacheDirectory=".phpunit.cache/code-coverage"
              processUncoveredFiles="true">
        <include>
            <directory suffix=".php">./app</directory>
        </include>
        <exclude>
            <directory suffix=".php">./app/Classes/Theme</directory>
            <file>./app/Http/Controllers/Controller.php</file>
            <file>./app/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php</file>
            <file>./app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php</file>
            <file>./app/Providers/BroadcastServiceProvider.php</file>
            <file>./app/Providers/MetronicServiceProvider.php</file>
        </exclude>
    </coverage>

    <php>
        <server name="APP_ENV" value=""/>
        <server name="TELESCOPE_ENABLED" value="false"/>
        <server name="BCRYPT_ROUNDS" value="4"/>
        <server name="CACHE_DRIVER" value="array"/>
        <server name="DB_CONNECTION" value="mysql"/>
        <server name="MAIL_MAILER" value="array"/>
        <server name="QUEUE_CONNECTION" value="sync"/>
        <server name="SESSION_DRIVER" value="array"/>
    </php>
</phpunit>
```

Comment: Please create a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). With the current information it's hard to reason what's going on.